# Apache basic authentication allow local network

Tags: apache, basic-authentication

Try to setup access to my apache 2.46 with password but NOT for the local network. Below code is not working. Allthough my access device is in the right IP range, even with a single IP below code is not working. Apache keeps asking for passw on my local network/ What is wrong with my code?

```
<Directory /var/www/mysite/>
    Options FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride none
    Order allow,deny
    Allow  from 192.168.1.1/24
    Deny from all
    AuthType Basic
    AuthName "Secure Content"
    AuthBasicProvider file
    AuthUserFile /etc/apache2/passwords
    Require  valid-user
    Satisfy any
 </Directory>
```

Comment: did you try giving the `Deny from all` before `Allow from 192.168.1.1/24`?

Comment: what do you mean, as far as I know order in this is not important

Comment: i disagree. i think you should read this http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/howto/htaccess.html#how

Comment: Tried this was not succesful, if I do this I still get asked for a password on the local network